# Check for duplicates in a column and if there is, check the colour of the cell to the right of the duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I need a program to check a column for duplicates and if there is, I want it to check the cell color to the right of it. if the color is orange, I want to change it to red, and if it is green, I want to ignore it.

```
    Dim lastRow As Integer, num As Integer, i As Integer

    lastRow = Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        If Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
            num = WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(i, 1), Range("A1:A" & lastRow), 0)
        End If
        If i = num Then
            If Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Then
                Cells(i, 2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

This is my current attempt at it, however this code only checks for the first time a duplicate appears and ignores the rest. The following [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63Xd8.png) will show you what I have, what the code does and what I want respectively. I hope I am clear with the question, sorry if I seem ignorant and thank you so much for helping in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: a bit more complex since you may need to "go back" and color a previous row...

```
Sub Tester()

    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet, rng As Range
    Dim dict As Object, v, c As Range, c2 As Range

    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")

    With ActiveSheet  'always use a worksheet reference...
        Set rng = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = c.Value
        Set c2 = c.Offset(0, 1)

        'potential row to recolor (orange)?
        If Len(v) > 0 And c2.Interior.ColorIndex = 44 Then

            If dict.exists(v) Then
                'is there a previous cell to color?
                If Not dict(v) Is Nothing Then
                    dict(v).Interior.ColorIndex = 3 'color the previous one
                    Set dict(v) = Nothing           'clear previous
                End If
                c2.Interior.ColorIndex = 3          'color the current one
            Else
                Set dict(v) = c2 'first orange one - remember it
            End If

        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, firstly, thanks for helping, but when I ran the code you provided, it simply change all the orange cells to red cells which is not what I needed. I only want to change it to a red cell if 2 conditions are satisfied, which is when the first column has the same number and when the cell next to it is orange. Thank you for your tip to use a worksheet reference though!

Comment: Hmmm, it still does the same thing though, all the orange cells just turned red.

Comment: I think your description of what you want is a little confusing - do you want all orange cells to the right of any number which appears more than once to be red, or only those orange cells which appear next to numbers which are paired with an orange cell more than once?

Comment: So sorry if I confused you but yes I would like the latter option. The picture I provide in post might help you understand what I need. column A and B is my initial input, column C and D is what my code in post gave me and column E and F is what I want. Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: Omg, thanks so much for helping, this is exactly what I needed. I been stucked on this for 2 days. Thank you for adding comments to let me understand each steps! Thanks again!!! :)